# Downloading a directory inside a git repo

Tags: git, jenkins

Being a git noob, this might be a dumb or impossible question.

My git repo looks like this.  If I run a

git clone ssh://fn.ln@blah.com:8443/blah.git

in my local directory, a sub directory called `blah` is created.  Inside the `blah` directory, I have these sub directories:

proj1
proj2
proj3
etc.

What I need to do is to be able to just pull down proj1 inside the blah.git repo for Jenkins to build.  I don't want to pull all the other projects if I just need to build proj1.

I've tried

git clone ssh://fn.ln@blah.com:8443/blah/proj1

but that returns a fatal error:

```
Cloning into 'proj1'...
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
```

I've skimmed a few resources online (Pro Git being one of them) but haven't found anything that answers this question.  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction of what to read or what to do.  If this action is not possible, you can laugh at me.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Is there a reason each project isn't in its own repo?

Comment: @Joe, i don't know.  i pointed out that another team has all their projects broken out (so they have like 30 different build jobs) and we have one dir but everything is inside that directory.  But a team member said we can specify on git to build a sub directory.  Of course, I was asked to look it up online how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this.  Git is pretty explicitly designed to hold one project per repository.

It's possible to only *check out* part of a repository (a "sparse checkout"), but last I checked it's still complicated and involves editing multiple config files and using Git plumbing commands.  And you'd have to combine that with a partial clone to even approximate what you're asking for.

Just split your repository up.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/17875) and give subtree a whirl.

Comment: where can I read more on git project/repo management? I don't think I'm knowledgeable enough in this area to defend doing it the proper way. After bringing it up in our team meeting today, a couple ppl was saying to keep the status quo. The argument is when you do a build, you're going to want to pull everything and then do a full build to run your test so keep everything under one repo. That doesn't fly with me but since I don't know enough, I don't have ground to stand on. I want to have each project in their own repo, then I can build it whenever I want it. (cont in next comment)

Comment: If there are any dependencies, I can control that too within Jenkins (I assume). Their argument against that is it's dangerous (which it might be since I'm error prone ;-)  ) but it's still better than pulling all 1000 projects worth of code just to build one project we want to test.  Thanks for your help and input

Comment: P.S.  If I don't make sense in what i'm asking, then just point me to something where it says best practices state each project must have its own repo :)   That's all I'm asking  :)

Comment: i don't know if there's anything comprehensive; this is just sort of common knowledge among most people i've known who use git—and the reason is partly that there just aren't sparse checkouts and everything is interwoven.  but clearly you don't always _want_ to pull down everything, or you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place  :)  submodules might help in the interim, but in the long term you will have much less pain using whatever package/dependency system your language/platform uses.

Comment: yeah, i'm not a git expert ;)  i was just using common sense and this is almost like object oriented programming. you separate things out to different classes so that if there's a change in one module, you don't need to compile the untouched module. we link them when needed and/or if there's a build order, we tell it what it is. i just don't know how to defend or express this view to people who for whatever reason don't want to do this. the only thing i can think of is it's easy to just go to one dir (in this case blah) and run git pull than to go to 30 dirs to do git pull and this is what

Comment: they are fighting for. hopefully i can find experts outside the group or read something online.  the next problem would be learning how to link everything on jenkins. someone told me i might need to use a pom.xml file or something to define dependencies but i'm just stumbling around right now since jenkins and git are both new to me